# Sharepoint - Calculate Remaining Workings Days - Date to Today

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to work out how to calculate the remaining works days between a set date in a sharepoint column and Today. However the below formula brings back a syntax error in sharepoint. Can someone advise?

=IF(NETWORKDAYS([Proposed Tender Submittal Date],TODAY())<=0,"",NETORKDAYS(TODAY(),[Proposed Tender Submittal Date]))

Comment: Did you look at this site: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/working-days-weekdays-holidays-sharepoint-calculated-columns/

Answer (score 1):

You refer the below formula which shows the difference between item created date and Today excluding weekends.

```
IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([Created],Today(),"d")),"",(DATEDIF([Created],Today(),"d"))+1-INT(DATEDIF([Created],Today(),"d")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY(Today())-WEEKDAY([Created]))<0,2,0)-IF(OR(AND(WEEKDAY(Today())=7,WEEKDAY([Created])=7),AND(WEEKDAY(Today())=1,WEEKDAY([Created])=1)),1,0)-IF(AND(WEEKDAY([Created])=1,(WEEKDAY(Today())-WEEKDAY([Created]))>0),1,0)-IF(AND(NOT(WEEKDAY([Created])=7),WEEKDAY(Today())=7),1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following link . It will give you hint.

http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/working-days-weekdays-holidays-sharepoint-calculated-columns/

Comment: Provide some context, not just a link.